# How to write a cycle for creating numpy arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, cycle

How to write this in cycle, please?

```
k1 = np.empty(np.shape(u))
k2 = np.empty(np.shape(u))
k3 = np.empty(np.shape(u))
k4 = np.empty(np.shape(u))
```

I tried:

```
 k = [k1, k2, k3, k4]

    for i in k:
        i = np.empty(np.shape(u))
    k.append(i)
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Get a list of four arrays? Or four arrays as separate variables? (The latter is probably not what you _really_ want.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use list comprehension to create an arbitrary number of empty numpy arrays

```
num = 10
result = [np.empty(np.shape(u)) for _ in range(num)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to do this, so I would recommend using lists or dictionaries but here's the code to achieve what you asked for-

```py
for x in range(0, n): #Replace n with the value you need
    globals()['k%s' % x] = np.empty(np.shape(u))
```

and then for example:

```
print(k1)
```

But again this is a bad practice, use dictionaries instead